# postgres timestamp extract date from bigint datatype

Tags: php, postgresql

I  inserted date (timestamp unix format) into postgres table using php. here below is the field structure.

```
last_dwnld
(bigint)
-----------
1408788007
1408190322
```

Field data type is **bigint** and its contain timestamp. field name is last_dwnld.

please let me know how to extract date using postgres query. 
**last_dwnld::DATE** is not helping here.

Comment: Consider converting that column to a timestamp column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres's internal to_timestamp function handles this (since 8.1)

```
Select to_timestamp(1408788007); -- 2014-08-23 10:00:07+00
```